# How to show tab content on the right side of the vertical navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am using Vue with bootstrap for my project:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-if="isLoading">
      <base-spinner></base-spinner>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

The output of the code above is as below:
[image: Screenshot]

The `tab-content` is showing below the `navigation bar`. How can I fix it so that the `tab-content` shows on the right side of the `navigation bar`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed it. Firstly, would need to wrap them in `container` class and create two divs with `col-sm` class.

Secondly, place all the `<a> tags` with `nav-link` class into the first `col-sm` div.

Thirdly, place all the tab contents into the second `col-sm` div.

Sample code as below. Thanks!

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-if="isLoading">
      <base-spinner></base-spinner>
    </div>
    <div v-else style="background-color:pink;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div
              class="nav flex-column nav-pills"
              id="v-pills-tab"
              role="tablist"
              aria-orientation="vertical"
            >
              <a
                class="nav-link active"
                id="v-pills-home-tab"
                data-toggle="pill"
                href="#v-pills-home"
                role="tab"
                aria-controls="v-pills-home"
                aria-selected="true"
                >Home</a
              >
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                id="v-pills-profile-tab"
                data-toggle="pill"
                href="#v-pills-profile"
                role="tab"
                aria-controls="v-pills-profile"
                aria-selected="false"
                >Profile</a
              >
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                id="v-pills-messages-tab"
                data-toggle="pill"
                href="#v-pills-messages"
                role="tab"
                aria-controls="v-pills-messages"
                aria-selected="false"
                >Messages</a
              >
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                id="v-pills-settings-tab"
                data-toggle="pill"
                href="#v-pills-settings"
                role="tab"
                aria-controls="v-pills-settings"
                aria-selected="false"
                >Settings</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
              <div
                class="tab-pane fade show active"
                id="v-pills-home"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
              >
                ...
              </div>
              <div
                class="tab-pane fade"
                id="v-pills-profile"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab"
              >
                ...
              </div>
              <div
                class="tab-pane fade"
                id="v-pills-messages"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab"
              >
                ...
              </div>
              <div
                class="tab-pane fade"
                id="v-pills-settings"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab"
              >
                ...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```